# Django 1.6 editing userprofile model with existing users

Tags: python, django

I have a django database with a custom user profile for the user model.
The problem is that when I want to add new fields to my userprofile class, I get the error `no such column`, regarding the new field, when trying to access the users table.

Any way then to update the userprofile model without having to rebuild the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it..

First install `south`

```
pip install south
```

Then add to your settings `INSTALLED_APP` list as -

```
   ...,
   'south',
   ...
```

What is south?.. Well south is a django app that helps you updating your database without having to rebuild it. Now initialise your models with-

```
python manage.py syncdb // this will create the south tables for migrations
python manage.py schemamigration <appname> --initial //  (once per app) this will create the initial model files in a migrations package
python manage.py migrate
```

Then every time you update your models just need to perform an update with  -

```
python manage.py schemamigration <appname> --auto
python manage.py migrate <appname>
```

You can find the full documentation here - http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mahmud, I already tried this before, but even doing it I still get the `no such column` error, and with south even if I redo the database I get the same error. I think I'm missing something there :(

Comment: Can you show the code or model that is causing the error?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It seems that I can't do that with existing fields.
First I must delete them (or modify them so south will delete and add the new one) and then run the migration with the new fields.
Migrating with old fields doesn't work :)

Comment: Yeah thats right. It computes the difference from `x_initial.py` file. So if it has the column then it won't create a new one.