# How to add new columns to django userprofile model

Tags: python, django

I have added one extra custom field `phone` to Django user authentication. Till then it worked properly. Later I added one more custom field called `permissions`. After that I am facing an error message when I try to access the admin page. Here is my `model.py` code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
                       ("ssc_1","can access ssc locked questions"),
                       )
    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    phone = models.CharField(max_length =20)
    permission = models.IntegerField()   

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I have followed [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407261/django-1-6-editing-userprofile-model-with-existing-users), when I issue `python manage.py migrate` command, I am getting this error message

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "users_userprofile" already exists
```

Note : My Django versions is 1.6.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Migrations were introduced only in django 1.7. Until then [south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) was being used to handle migrations